# how to sum 2 specific field of array if id was same in php

Tags: php, arrays

Guys I want to sum two array fields `liked_cnt , coupon_cnt`  if first field `id` is same
how can I do this?

I did this but its toooooo slow

```
if (end($like)['id'] > end($coupon)['id']) {
          $i = end($like)['id'];
          $j = end($coupon)['id'];
        }else {
          $i = end($coupon)['id'];
          $j = end($like)['id'];
        }

        for ($k=0; $k <= $i; $k++) {
          for ($l=0; $l  < $j; $l++) {
            if ($like['id'] == $coupon['id']) {
              $score[$like['id']] = ($coupon['coupon_cnt'] * 1000) + $like['liked_cnt'];
            }else {
              $score[$i] = 0;
            }
          }
        }



//first array $Like

Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 85 [liked_cnt] => 6 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 86 [liked_cnt] => 14 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 92 [liked_cnt] => 6 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 93 [liked_cnt] => 6 ) 

//second array $coupon
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 35 [coupon_cnt] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 86 [coupon_cnt] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 139 [coupon_cnt] => 1 ) )
```

Comment: What have you tried , post your code

Comment: @Rahul I update the code, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic algorithm builtin to php that can really compute your desired result in a much more efficient way. This might be slightly more efficient, but most of all it is more readable:

```
<?php
$input = [
    [
        ['id' => 85, 'liked_cnt' => 6],
        ['id' => 86, 'liked_cnt' => 14],
        ['id' => 92, 'liked_cnt' => 6],
        ['id' => 93, 'liked_cnt' => 6]
    ],
    [
        ['id' => 35, 'coupon_cnt' => 2],
        ['id' => 86, 'coupon_cnt' => 1],
        ['id' => 139, 'coupon_cnt' => 1]
    ]
];

$output = [];
foreach ($input as $set) {
    array_walk($set, function($entry) use (&$output) {
        $count = array_pop($entry);
        $id = array_pop($entry);
        if (array_key_exists($id, $output)) {
            $output[$id]['total_cnt'] += $count;
        } else {
            $output[$id] = ['id' => $id, 'total_cnt' => $count];
        }
    });
}
print_r(array_values($output));
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 85
            [total_cnt] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 86
            [total_cnt] => 15
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 92
            [total_cnt] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 93
            [total_cnt] => 6
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 35
            [total_cnt] => 2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 139
            [total_cnt] => 1
        )

)
```

---

UPDATE:

Considering your third comment below I add this modified version introducing the general multiplication of the `coupon_cnt` attribute by a factor 1000:

```
<?php
$input = [
    [
        ['id' => 85, 'liked_cnt' => 6],
        ['id' => 86, 'liked_cnt' => 14],
        ['id' => 92, 'liked_cnt' => 6],
        ['id' => 93, 'liked_cnt' => 6]
    ],
    [
        ['id' => 35, 'coupon_cnt' => 2],
        ['id' => 86, 'coupon_cnt' => 1],
        ['id' => 139, 'coupon_cnt' => 1],
        ['id' => 99, 'coupon_cnt' => 99]
    ]
];

$output = [];
foreach ($input as $set) {
    array_walk($set, function($entry) use (&$output) {
        $count = array_key_exists('coupon_cnt', $entry)
               ? 1000 * array_pop($entry)
               : array_pop($entry);
        $id = array_pop($entry);
        if (array_key_exists($id, $output)) {
            $output[$id]['total_cnt'] += $count;
        } else {
            $output[$id] = ['id' => $id, 'total_cnt' => $count];
        }
    });
}
print_r(array_values($output));
```

Comment: thanks the answer is right and useful but can you help me a little more to multiply `(coupon_cnt * 1000) + liked_cnt` thank you

Comment: @MasoudTavakkoli You mean `$output[$id]['total_cnt'] += 1000 * $count;`?

Comment: Hi again, sorry I have a little problem your code work perfect but have a tiny bug. when a user have no like but have coupon `total_cnt` doesn't multiply  coupons to 1000. how can I do this? I am so sorry for my question

Comment: Your requirements are very vague, you may have to be much more specific as to when that attribute is to be multiplied by a factor 1000. I added a modified version, I _think_ that is what you are looking for. But as said: you'd have to be more specific.

Comment: sorry for my weak explanation. this wasn't work for me. I explain one more time maybe I could say in better way. I wanna list my users and sort them via score. score obtained from 2 parameter. first from users post likes that it is possible user, have no likes (`like_cnt = 0`) and every like is 1. Second is coupon score that every coupon is 1000 score and maybe a user have not any coupon